# How to make image in middle in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

> I want to align 5 images in the page, i want to put three images in row in the middle of the page and in the next row i want to put two images below those in the row in the middle but it is not happening,Can anyone help me to sort out

```
 <div class="top container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/1.png">
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/1.png">
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/1.png">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="top1 container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/2.png">
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/2.png">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use col-md-offset to adjust both div's  left offset keep changing offset vaue like offset-2 or offset-4 maybe u will get required effect  first,. try col-md-offset-2 on top1 div first section .

Answer (score 0):

**use:**

```
<div class="top container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <img src="images/1.png">
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/1.png">
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/1.png">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="top1 container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <img src="images/2.png">
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <img src="images/2.png">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry Brother its not happening

Comment: Some detail about why that answer works would be helpful. Just posting code doesn't give any detail about why that answers the question and how exactly it works.